# Intersection and union of hashsets

Tags: c, set, hashtable

I have a hash table data structure where each element in the associative array is a linked list and each node in the linked list has a string as its data. The key for the hash function is the string which is inserted into the hash table. Is the intersection of these two hash tables a hash table which only contains linked lists which are fully present in both of the two hash tables which it is intersecting? Or is it just the nodes with unique strings that exist in both hash tables in any index in their associative arrays? Same thing for the union operation.

Comment: Isn't this something which depends on requirement? Although, I tend to the latter: _just the nodes with unique strings that exist in both hash tables_ Consider, that usually the hash codes are not the payload a user is interested in but the hashed values (strings in your case) are. Intersecting or unifying the hash codes (regardless of payload) may surprise the user.

Comment: Its an upcoming potential exam question for college. I'm not sure how to answer it. I was leading towards the full linked list since intersection is defined as identical elements in both which would require the entire linked lists to be equal but I'm still not sure.

Comment: Imagine a certain set of strings (and a certain set of another). Both are stored in hash tables (for fast search). After intersection or union, I would expect a proper result concerning the original string sets - regardless how they've been hashed (and how many of them share the same hash value due to collisions). This in mind, I clearly would vote for the latter: _just the nodes with unique strings that exist in both hash tables_ In other words, the kind of container internals shouldn't influence how the result of intersection or union comes out.